# Compiling a list : python best practice

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I am often compiling lists one element at a time in python 3; say for instance I am making a list by going through a linked list with first element **head**:

```
l = []
while head:
    l.append(head.val)
    head = head.next
```

I was wondering what the best practices are. Is there another way of writing this? Could it be possible to describe the list in one line, with something like this instead:

```
while head:
    l = # something creating the list AND appending elements
    head = head.next
```

Even better: do I always have to use a loop to create lists in similar cases, or are there often ways to make the desired list in one line ?

Thanks!

EDIT : a typo in the code !

Comment: Yes. Look into list comprehensions! You can do very complex things like `[i for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0]`

The first tutorial on google: https://hackernoon.com/list-comprehension-in-python-8895a785550b

Comment: @Reedinationer: List comprehensions have their limitations--one of the major changes in Python 3.8 will be the ability to do assignments in expressions, and much of the purpose is to allow list comprehensions to be more powerful. It is not at all obvious to me how to solve the questioner's problem with a comprehension (without using a function created for this purpose).

Comment: Are you often working with your own bespoke linked-lists?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, they are formulated just as written in Olivier Melançon's answer

Comment: @Jeffery may I ask why? What do they provide that isn't provided by the standard library? e.g. just the vanilla `list` or a `collections.deque`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's just the simplest example I could find of *something* not quite standard that I need to turn into a list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an OOP perspective, the best practice is to rely on Python's `__iter__` method to cast an iterable to a `list`.

I am assuming your linked-list `class` looks a bit like this.

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value, nxt=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = nxt
```

To allow iteration on your linked-list, you can define `__iter__`

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value, nxt=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = nxt

    def __iter__(self):
        while self:
            yield self.value
            self = self.next
```

You can then let `list` handle the cast of the `LinkedList` iterable.

```
head = LinkedList(1, LinkedList(2, LinkedList(3)))
lst = list(head) # [1, 2, 3]
```